# CakePHP form in facebook validates on initial load

Tags: facebook, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have a simple form in CakePHP (version 2.4). If I open the url in the browser everything is OK, the form only validates after I click Submit for the first time. But if I put that same form inside Facebook app (as Page Tab) the same form validates right away and outputs all the errors before user even clicks Submit (ofcourse because all the required fields are empty on initial load).

My controler for the Form Add:

```
public function add($id = null) {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', "Fb Form");

    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Application->create($this->data);
        if ($this->Application->save()) {
            $this->Application->saveField('fbapp_id', $id);
            $this->Session->setFlash('Form saved');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Form not saved');
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated so thnx in advance!

Comment: You should provide the CakePHP version...

Comment: Sorry, edited the post and added a tag. I'm using Cake 2.4 Thnx for noticing!

Comment: Your validation is likely triggered simply by the request method being POST … and as you know, apps get loaded into the Facebook iframe by POSTing a form to the iframe …

Comment: Try to check on empty and isset: `if (!empty($this->data) && isset($this->data['Application']))`

Comment: What is the best workaround around that so that users don't always see all the errors before actually submitting?

Comment: @noslone Thank you that worked, also checking isset! Thnx again